# ein völlig Unbekannter oder ein völliger Unbekannter

Tags: adjective, adverb

Is here *völlig* adverbial oder an adjective ?

Would you agree with this example sentence :

> Es gibt Grund zur Sorge, wenn man feststellt,
> dass die einschmeichelnden Reden
> von völligen Unbekannten
> die Mehrheit der Bevölkerung täuschen können.

I would tend to prefer

> Es gibt Grund zur Sorge, wenn man feststellt,
> dass die einschmeichelnden Reden
> von völlig Unbekannten
> die Mehrheit der Bevölkerung täuschen können.

Comment: note, *völliger Unsinn* may be *folly nonsense* instead of *full-on nonsense*, thus a mean corruption of *fool*, while *vollig sch...* is *fulla sh?t*, further reduced to *voll sch.*. On another  ote, I have recently heard for the first time *das ist das ganze Gegenteil* instead of *ganz'm Gegenteil*, so there may be precedent for \*völliger unbekannter as well, that was someone from Saxony, Leipzig area I believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, it should be "von völlig Unbekannten". The adjective "völlig" further characterizes the quality "unbekannt" (unknown), not the persons who are meant by "die Unbekannten", and in German, like in English, an adverb or the adverbial form of an adjective is used to further qualify another adjective.

> ein rot markiertes Buch *=> the book has a red marker*
> ein rotes markiertes Buch *=> the book is red and is marked somehow*

It's a common mistake with native speakers. "Völlige Unbekannte" somehow sounds stronger than "völlig Unbekannte", the subtle difference can sometimes get lost in the heat of despise.

Comment: I guess you mean "with _non_-native speakers"?

Comment: @Don Holgo: No, in my experience Germans do this quite often, especially in spoken language.

Comment: At least in this context, "völlig" is an adverb, not an adjective.

Comment: @fdb, "völlig" is of Wortart adjective, and "völlig" is also its adverbial form, which is used here, it's an adverbially used adjective. I edited to make this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

ein völlig Unbekannter is right!

its an adjective:

**Question:**

Wie ist es?

**Answer:**

Völlig unbekannt

Comment: *What* is an adjective? "völlig" or "unbekannt"? The way your question/answer pair is written, it appears you want to point out that "unbekannt" is an adjective, but while correct, that is not what the question is asking about.